# How to use Efficient indexing (numpy) in cython in both .pxd and .pyx file

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Suppose I have `.pxd` and `.pyx` file, they all use function argument like this : `np.ndarray[DTYPE_double_t, ndim=1] weight`, but ctypedef in both file(pyx and pxd) will occur: '`DTYPE_int_t`' redeclared

my code is following in both file start part:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
DTYPE_double = np.float64
DTYPE_int = np.int32
ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_double_t
ctypedef np.int32_t DTYPE_int_t
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Cython documentation on [pxd files](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/pxd_files.html)

> When accompanying an equally named pyx file, they provide a Cython
>   interface to the Cython module so that other Cython modules can
>   communicate with it using a more efficient protocol than the Python
>   one.

This means that copying declarations from the `.pxd` file to the `.pyx` file is an error as it will be included automatically. To compile your code, you  must remove the duplication.

You have not stated why you wish to duplicate the code, so if it is important for some purpose please explain why so I or others can help you to resolve the issue.

Comment: I write an function define in pxd file declaration:cpdef belief_propagation(self, int max_iter, np.ndarray[DTYPE_float_t, ndim=1] weight),   but this function also must occur in corresponding pyx file. So the ctypedef np.float64_t DTYPE_double_t must occur in both files.

Comment: It is enough to place it in the `.pxd` file. Definitions from the `.pxd` file will be in the `.pyx` file. For plain definitions this is alright. For `cdef`-ed or `cpdef`-ed functions, only the signature goes in the `.pxd` file and the full definition in the `.pyx` file. If you want more precise help, a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be necessary.